# I have a issue with jquery search, hightlight and jump to the highlighted code

Tags: jquery, search, replace, highlight

I am using this code from [this site](http://teeohhem.com/2011/02/20/search-for-and-highlight-text-on-a-page-with-jquery/#comment-342)
and also have the [running jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7fjW/134/).
I notice that when you search in the fiddle example, the word you type is replaced to the actual result and I am trying to remove it as I need to only find and highlight. Also I got error if you search for " ", I am trying to solve it by tweaking the code but I am honestly not understanding the whole process. Any help would be really welcome.

```
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
if(searchTerm) {
    //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
    //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
    var selector = selector || "body";                             //default selector is body if none provided
    var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm,"ig");
    var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
    if(matches) {
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');     //Remove old search highlights
        $(selector).html($(selector).html()
                .replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='highlighted'>"+searchTerm+"</span>"));
        if($('.highlighted:first').length) {             //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
            $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search-button').on("click",function() {
            if(!searchAndHighlight($('#search-term').val(), "#bass")) {
                alert("No hay resultados");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What gaurav5430 said you did was right. You are taking your search term and replacing it with the actual letter. What you need to do is get the capture term and highlight it. I'm pretty sure there's more efficient ways but my quick and dirty way is under the if(matches) case

```
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');       //Remove old search highlights
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < matches.length; ++index) {  //Go through all the matched cases 
            var wordreg = new RegExp(matches[index]);       //get a new regex that has the exact casing and wording
            $(selector).html($(selector).html()             //then find that and replace it with right casings
                .replace(wordreg, "<span class='highlighted'>"+matches[index] +"</span>"));
        }

        if($('.highlighted:first').length) {             //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
            $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
        }
        return true;
```

Its ugly but it works. Here's the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z7fjW/265/

**EDIT

When you regex a text, you'll get back an array of strings that matches. For example: you search 'Hey' in 'Hey hey hEY heY', you get back an array of strings ['Hey', 'hey', 'hEY', 'heY'].

You have to loop through this array, find the strings that corresponds (matches) with the regex that doesn't ignore case and then replace with the highlighted one. Look at the for loop in my code.

Comment: You should follow gaurav5430 advice as well, its searching the whole body so if you search 'search' the search bar gets replaced

Comment: thanks man, i already added and works fine, but i noticed that now only select one result in all document, how could i modify to also find all the results?

Comment: Ok now i read about regex and add the modifiers to "ig" and solve the highlight on multiple words, now how could i solve the msg: "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding", i read in this site some answers and says that there maybe a loop, i check the code and as my understanding reads it's good i don't see what should be the heavy task in that :/

Comment: can u jsfiddle what u have now?

Comment: sure, i end it up with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/gabouh075/U7nYt/

It works, fine but in my particular project in the replace section i had to use match[1] because i am getting a different array with eight elements. I really don't know why yet, i run some test in the big pile of text i am searching and if i try the word "oscar" in my complete arrey of eight elements contains: ["osCar", "Oscar", "Oscar", "Oscar", "Oscar", "Oscar", "Oscar", "Oscar"] 

Also am having issue in Chrome where it find the text and the jump off to a lower part of the window

Comment: you're doing the same thing as before.. you're replacing all the elements with the first match instead of the right matches. Look at my editted answer

Comment: yeah i did see your answer and am replacing the founded with the matches[1] in my projecto as the second element as i can tell in the console.log look exactly to the result i need it. I use the for loop, but started to take much time and sometimes it crash and i try those changes

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var selector = selector || "body";
```

with

```
 var selector = selector || "#bodyContainer";
```

Explanaion:

the problem was that your `regex` was matching for values within the `body tag`,i.e., it was also trying to match the values of the `children tags` like the 'b' in '`<br>`' .

the expected behavior is to search only inside the `container` which contains the data, which is `bodyContainer`

EDIT: based on comments.

that is because the `regex is ignoring case for matching` and your `replace function replaces the found value with the query string`. so if found value is EMPTY and the query string is eMpTy, your regex will match it, and your replace function will replace the actual value with the query text (along with adding spans)

Comment: Hi, i try what you said and change the selector to #bodyContainer and it still works, my issue in the fiddle example is that if in the search box you input "empty" then the first result if is "Empty", will be replaced with the result "empty", and that i what i still can't make it work.